# How to position elements in a table in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Pandas, and I would like to reposition elements with the columns, I currently have:

| Type Label | Initial | 2022 | 2023 | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| APPS | A/B/C | 500 | 469 | 31 |
| BACS | B/C/D | 5 | 3 | 2 |
| CAPS | C/D/E | 10 | 5 | 5 |

I would like to have the table to be displayed like this:

| Type Label/Initial | 2022 | 2023 | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **APPS** | 500 | 469 | 31 |
| A |  |  |  |
| B |  |  |  |
| C |  |  |  |
| **BACS** | 5 | 3 | 2 |
| B |  |  |  |
| C |  |  |  |
| D |  |  |  |
| **CAPS** | 10 | 5 | 5 |
| C |  |  |  |
| D |  |  |  |
| E |  |  |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join columns `Type` and `Initial` with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for droping column, then split by `/` and use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), rename columns names and set empty string for repeated values:

```
s = (df['Type Label'] + '/ ' + df.pop('Initial')).str.split('/')
df = df.assign(**{'Type Label':s} ).explode('Type Label').rename(columns={'Type Label':'Type Label/Initial'})
df.iloc[:, 1:] = df.iloc[:, 1:].mask(df.index.to_series().duplicated(), '')
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   Type Label/Initial 2022 2023 Difference
0          APPS  500  469         31
1             A                     
2             B                     
3             C                     
4          BACS    5    3          2
5             B                     
6             C                     
7             D                     
8          CAPS   10    5          5
9             C                     
10            D                     
11            E
```

Comment: The table has been updated Further with the first column being Type Label so with your solution could I start with:   s = (df['Type Label'] + '/ ' + df.pop('Initial')).str.split('/') ?

Comment: @MrMann yea,  you are right

Comment: @MrMann Can you test now? I iam on phone only, so not tested.

Comment: all working now thanks again